# How to change Ubuntu root directory on termux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Recently i have installed Ubuntu on my termux app. So i don't now how to change it's root directory. I have installed it on a very bad path. This is the link
https://gist.github.com/tmatz/817bf03433e059bf89c63dc33f286ccb#3-install-ubuntu

I ran the Ubuntu.sh in a subfolder. So its to hard to access it from my termux home directory.

And i copied the startubuntu.sh and of course it gave an error. There's no problem if i have to reinstall it. Or a way to delete it so i can install it again.

Can you guys help me with that? Thanks